# EmberJS router and external library

Tags: ember.js, routes, pdf.js

I have currently difficulties in using the EmberJS router and an external library. 
Using the EmberJS router, the routing functionality works perfectly.
Also the inclusion of the external library within a component works as expected.

BUT the combination of both is not working.

In detail: the library (pdf.js) is manipulating the DOM and inserting anchor tags while scrolling through the document. These anchor tags work fine. But if I try to "catch" the event and use the EmberJS routing functionality, it is not working!
I cannot create an eventlistener in the DidRender() function and use preventDefault, because the elements are not present during the time of execution of DidRender.

Did anyone face the same issue or maybe has a solution for this problem?

Cheers,
Franz

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are using a component,

Init 3-rd party lib inside `didInsertElement` hook instead of `DidRender`.

The DOM is ready inside that hook and you can assess the component HTML element using `this.$()`.

What does this mean?

> But if I try to "catch" the event and use the EmberJS routing functionality, it is not working!

DOM manipulation operations are all sync operations. Bind the your own even handler inside the `didInsertElement` hook too, but pay close attention to your `this` context.

Comment: Yes, I already initialize the lib in the didInsertElement but since the lib is modifying the DOM on the fly, I ran into the mentioned problem.

Comment: Can you explain more on what does the quoted above means?